# writing a Bingo Game in java

Tags: java, swing

I'm totally new to Java and on my second self-project.
I'm trying to write a bingo game. I know there are some posts about this, but I think that my approach is a little bit different from others', so sorry if it looks redundant. 
My bingo game is 5x5 matrix with 25 buttons and I labled them from 1~25 just for convenience. I also made a pseudo game board called **grid** variable which is a 5x5 2d Character Array. It's originially filled with 'O's but when I press on one of the buttons, then the corresponding index turns into 'X'. I'm using this **grid** to check for bingos since I thought it would be a lot easier than checking the actual buttons. Below is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
public class exex extends JFrame{
    final int size =5; //5x5 bingo board
    int bingos =0; // how many bingos?
    int count=0; // int value for each btn
    JButton[][] btn = new JButton[size][size]; //actual display of btns (bingo board) 
    char[][] grid = new char[size][size]; // grid to check whether it's bingo or not
    int presscount = 1; // how many times ive pressed
    int row; // row for action event
    int column; // column for action event
    boolean bingo; //check if bingo
    exex(){
        setTitle("Bingo for everyone");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(size,size));//basic board setup
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            btn[i][j] = new JButton(Integer.toString(count)); //setting buttons 1~25;
            grid[i][j] ='O'; // make a grid board to check bingos
            btn[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
                    isBingo(grid,'X'); // check if grid has any bingos, if it does, then set bingo to true.
                    System.out.print(bingo);
                    if(bingo){
                        bingos++;
                    }
                    System.out.print(bingos);
                    JButton btnR = (JButton)e.getSource();
                    System.out.println(presscount);
                    presscount++;
                    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                            if(btn[i][j] == btnR){
                                row = i;
                                column =j;
                                grid[row][column]='X'; //set pressed button to 'X' char on my grid(2D char array)
                            }
                            System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
                        }
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                    System.out.println("-----------");


                //Color change when pressed, 
                        btnR.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        btnR.setOpaque(true);


                }
            });
            add(btn[i][j]);
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);

}
public void isBingo(char[][] array,char g){
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
            if(array[0][j]==g&&array[1][j]==g&&array[2][j]==g&&array[3][j]==g&&array[4][j]==g){ //check for vertical bingos
                bingo = true;
            }
            else if(array[i][0]==g&&array[i][1]==g&&array[i][2]==g&&array[i][3]==g&&array[i][4]==g){//check for horizontal bingos
                bingo = true;
            }
            else if(array[0][0]==g&&array[1][1]==g&&array[2][2]==g&&array[3][3]==g&&array[4][4]==g){ //check for S.E diagonal bingos
                bingo =true;
            }
            else if(array[0][4]==g&&array[1][3]==g&&array[2][2]==g&&array[3][1]==g&&array[4][0]==g){ //check for S.W diagonal bingos
                bingo= true;
            }
            else // if no bingos, remains false
                bingo = false;
        }
    }   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new exex();


}
```

}

So the problem is if I make one bingo in any direction, then I'm not sure how to count the next bingos I make. Since a bingo in any direction will set my ***boolean bingo***  to true and it will remain true as long as there is a bingo... any additional bingos will not be counted.. How would I fix this? 
I know the code is really messy and is not well written. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't set `bingo = false` in the inner loop of `isBingo`. Set it to false once, at the start of your `isBingo` method. However, it would be a much better style not to use the `bingo` member variable, and then simply return a boolean from this method.

Comment: Also, your diagonal bingos don't need to be checked in the loop - you aren't using `i` or `j` to evaluate them.

Comment: If you're actually a beginner and this is your second program, I suggest you take it easy and scale back quite a bit, maybe even start over with a couple of simple hello-world type programs. Get to know the language and the library first, then when you're comfortable with that make a small and simple Swing program, showing just a window, and work your way from there, adding one small piece at a time. Get the GUI right first (piece by piece) then think about the game and its rules, and how to handle each button and event.

Comment: I learned the very basic cores(methods, classes etc) of java and I thought doing this kind of project would teach me APIs and stuff that I haven't learned. Thank you for the suggestion tho!

Comment: @AndyTurner, I added bingo = false at the first line of isBingo()method but the bingos(variable that counts bingos) still goes up even if I don't make additional bingos after one.

Comment: If you just need to count the number of bingos, you can increment a `bingoCount` variable instead of setting a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems, you´re overriding your boolean bingo variable in the loop in isBingo. So mostly no bingo really returns true. I have removed some class attributes and put them in the contexts, they are needed to calculate an unique result. Also i put a possibility to store the bingos already happened...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class exex extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1172300329115978744L;

    final int size = 5; // 5x5 bingo board
    int bingos = 0; // how many bingos?
    JButton[][] btn = new JButton[size][size]; // actual display of btns (bingo
                                                // board)
    char[][] grid = new char[size][size]; // grid to check whether it's bingo or
                                            // not
    int presscount = 1; // how many times ive pressed

    boolean[] rowBingos = new boolean[size];
    boolean[] columnBingos = new boolean[size];
    boolean se, sw;

    exex() {
        setTitle("Bingo for everyone");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(size, size));// basic board setup
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                btn[i][j] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i * 5 + j + 1)); // setting
                                                                            // buttons
                                                                            // 1~25;
                grid[i][j] = 'O'; // make a grid board to check bingos
                btn[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JButton btnR = (JButton) e.getSource();
                        System.out.println(presscount);
                        presscount++;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                                if (btn[i][j] == btnR) {
                                    int row = i;
                                    int column = j;
                                    grid[row][column] = 'X'; // set pressed
                                                                // button to 'X'
                                                                // char on my
                                                                // grid(2D char
                                                                // array)
                                }
                                System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
                            }
                            System.out.println("");
                        }
                        boolean bingo = isBingo('X'); // check if grid has
                                                        // any bingos, if it
                                                        // does, then set
                                                        // bingo to true.
                        System.out.print(bingo);
                        if (bingo) {
                            bingos++;
                        }
                        System.out.print(bingos);
                        System.out.println("-----------");

                        // Color change when pressed,
                        btnR.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        btnR.setOpaque(true);

                    }
                });
                add(btn[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public boolean isBingo(char g) {
        if (grid[0][0] == g && grid[1][1] == g
                && grid[2][2] == g && grid[3][3] == g
                && grid[4][4] == g && se != true) { // check for S.E
                                                    // diagonal bingos
            se = true;
            return true;
        } else if (grid[0][4] == g && grid[1][3] == g
                && grid[2][2] == g && grid[3][1] == g
                && grid[4][0] == g && sw != true) { // check for S.W
                                                    // diagonal bingos
            sw = true;
            return true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                if (grid[0][j] == g && grid[1][j] == g && grid[2][j] == g
                        && grid[3][j] == g && grid[4][j] == g
                        && columnBingos[j] != true) { // check for
                    // vertical
                    // bingos
                    columnBingos[j] = true;
                    return true;
                } else if (grid[i][0] == g && grid[i][1] == g
                        && grid[i][2] == g && grid[i][3] == g
                        && grid[i][4] == g && rowBingos[i] != true) {// check
                                                                        // for
                                                                        // horizontal
                                                                        // bingos
                    rowBingos[i] = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        // if no bingos, remains false
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new exex();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just add some identification for each 'cell' like for example there is in excel. Then generate Character Sequence on all of the bingos and store in set so not to count it twice (a bingo could be something lke ABCD from top row). Then you just do the same thing now, just check if a bingo is already stored in the set, if not save it into set and increment the bingo number. This would require you to get rid of the boolean. You dont really need it either as you can always check if int bingos is greater than 0.